# How do I add a a dropdown menu in the default asp .net 3.1 razor template

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

By default, when you create a page in asp .net core 3.1 (in Visual Studio of course) you get a base menus in _layout.cshtml:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Axinco.JuryTool.Interface.Gui</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
            <partial name="_LoginPartial"/>
            <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

This gives you the following layout:

[image: Default webpage]

I added code to download extra menu settings based on the role. Basically, it's a menuheader (for example 'Adminisrator') and then a couple of menu items.

So I want to add a down menu next to "Privacy".

How would I best do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I added code to download extra menu settings based on the role.
> Basically, it's a menuheader (for example 'Adminisrator') and then a
> couple of menu items.

Based on **user's roles**, you can create a down menu as follow:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> userManger   
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
                <div class="container">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">WebApplication_core_identity2</a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                            aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
                        <partial name="_LoginPartial" />
                        <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-info" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                    Roles
                                </a>
                                @{if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                                    {
                                        var user = await userManger.GetUserAsync(User);
                                        var rolesArray = userManger.GetRolesAsync(user).Result;
                                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                            @foreach (var role in rolesArray)
                                            {
                                                <button type="button" class="dropdown-item btn btn-info btn-sm">@role</button>
                                            }
                                        </div>
                                    }
                                }
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
```

Here is the test result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use following code : You'll need to include bootstrap css and Js.

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Axinco.JuryTool.Interface.Gui</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
                <partial name="_LoginPartial" />
                <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
                    </li>


                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-info" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Test drodown
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <form asp-area="" asp-controller="Login" asp-action="Logout" method="post">
                                <button type="submit" class="dropdown-item btn btn-info btn-sm">Logout</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on one of the answers here I managed to get it up & running:

```
    @{
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            @if (userMenus != null && userMenus.Count > 0)
            {
                @foreach (var userMenu in userMenus)
                {
                    //  Debug
                    var debugLine = $"userMenu = {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userMenu)}";
                    Debug.WriteLine(debugLine);

                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-info" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        @userMenu.Caption
                        </a>

                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            @foreach (var menuItem in userMenu.MenuElements)
                            {
                                //  Debug
                                debugLine = $"userMenu = {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userMenu)}";
                                Debug.WriteLine(debugLine);

                                <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area=@menuItem.AspArea asp-controller=@menuItem.AspController asp-action=@menuItem.AspAction>@menuItem.ElementName</a>
                            }
                        </div>
                    </li>
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This gives the following result:

[image: web result]

I only have one remaining question: how do I get rid of this one "icon" on the left of " Home"?

Anyone any ideas.